# Puppet creating file on an agent

Tags: puppet

I'm running a puppet code that create a file with text, it's working when I'm running it locally (with puppet apply <.pp file> on the same machine) but not working when I'm running the code on an agent from a puppet master server (with puppet agent -t on the manifests directory) my code:

```
node default {
  file { '/test544/newdirha1': #the path of the new file
    ensure => 'present',
    content => 'this is the content', #this text will be inside the file
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    mode => '0644',
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it not working because the `/test544` does not exist on the client filesystem? Without an error message we can only speculate.

Comment: Hi, test544 folder is exists in the puppet agent, and there is not any errors when I`m running the pp file on the puppet server (the puppet master):
[root@puppetserver manifests]# puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for puppet
Info: Applying configuration version '1550060319'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.02 seconds

Comment: That the catalog run completes successfully and very quickly without applying the file suggests that the agent is receiving an empty catalog.  That could arise for various reasons, prominent among them that the manifest containing node declaration is in the wrong place or is not readable by the catalog compiler, or that the master's environment cache needs to be cleared (restarting the master service is an easy way to achieve that).  To judge between these and possibly others, we need more information.

Comment: Hi John, two puppet machines: master and agent - has been rebooted, just in case any of the system services need a restart, and still not working.
Please tell me/guide me how to provide you relevant information.
Thanks!

Comment: To start, let's have the pathname of your manifest on the server, relative to Puppet's base directory.  Also, if the manifest contains anything more than what you've already presented then that would be relevant, too, as would be the contents of any (other) manifests in the relevant environment's site manifest directory.  And what version of Puppet are you using?

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger.

puppet master server:
puppet version: 3.8.7
puppet pathname: /etc/puppet
puppet manifest pathname: /etc/puppet/manifests (the only one manifests directory on the server)

puppet agent server:
puppet version: 3.8.7
puppet pathname: /etc/puppet

The manifest contains anything more than what you've already presented? no

Comment: @user3383886, by "pathname of your manifest", I meant the full path, including name, of the .pp file containing the node declaration you present.  Similarly, by "other manifests" I meant other .pp files.  The term "manifest" is Puppet jargon for input files written in Puppet DSL and, conventionally, bearing the .pp extension.

Comment: @JohnBollinger.
[root@puppetserver manifests]# pwd
/etc/puppet/manifests
[root@puppetserver manifests]# ll
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 224 Feb 13 11:59 woot3.pp
[root@puppetserver manifests]#

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the master does not read or process your manifest file at all.

Puppet 3.8 is obsolete and unsupported.  The latest us Puppet 6.2, and since you're just getting going I recommend starting there.  The expected layout and behavior of that and other more recent Puppet versions differ in some import and relevant ways, but in Puppet 3, the starting point for the master's processing is a *single* file, the "site manifest", which by default is `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`.

Your master having neither a site manifest nor an external node classifier to rely upon, it will not assign any classes or resources to any node.  It will generate only empty catalogs, which is exactly what you observe.  Your manifest `woot3.pp` is ignored.  The simplest and most direct way to solve the problem would be to rename `woot3.pp` to `site.pp`.